# INSERT INTO / SELECT DISTINCT results in primary key violation for a SYS_GUID

Tags: sql, oracle

I had some problems bulk inserting data from another table into a new one. The target looked somewhat like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_T (
      T_GUID RAW(16) DEFAULT SYS_GUID() NOT NULL,
      T_VAL1 NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
      T_VAL2 VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (T_GUID)
)
```

The simplified version of the statement I intended to fill it with data:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_T (T_VAL1, T_VAL2)
SELECT DISTINCT
     CAST(SUBSTR(zip_code, 1,1) AS NUMBER) as  t_val1,
     zip_code as t_val2
FROM OTHER_TABLE_T
WHERE ...
ORDER BY t_val1
```

As I'm not providing a `T_GUID` valued, I would've assumed that I get one provided by the `SYS_GUID` function for each new line. But something is going wrong, and I get a uniqueness constraint violation for the primary key.

If I remove the `DISTINCT`, the statement succeeds, but I get lots of duplicate entries. And, of course, if I explicitly provide a `SYS_GUID()` call in my `SELECT`, that has exactly the same result.

Now I found that if I simply put another `SELECT` around mine, it works out alright, no constraint violations and the distinct rows get inserted:

```
INSERT INTO ...
SELECT x.* FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ...
) x
```

So where do the duplicate guids come from? If the full set of rows doesn't have problems, why would removing rows via distinct cause trouble? As SYS_GUID creates a unique identifier for each call, I could only imagine that in the distinct case it only gets called once for the whole clause, which is solved by the surrounding wrapping `SELECT`. I'd be very happy if someone could explain how the execution differs in that case.

Comment: Are you sure the guids are duplicates? Look very closely at them, they look similar but you should notice at least one character different in each of them.

Comment: Your code looks correct. You may be hitting an Oracle bug, look up "DUPLICATE SYS_GUID generated on AIX can lead to ORA-1 errors during enqueue [ID 1371805.1]" on My Oracle Support.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
insert into test_t(t_guid, t_val1, t_val2)
  select sys_guid(), t_val1, t_val2
    from (select distinct to_number(substr(zip_code, 1, 1)) as t_val1, zip_code as t_val2
            from other_table_t
           where ...)
```

Comment: I don't even need to do that. As I wrote above, as soon as I do `select * from (select distinct ...`, it works. I just have no good explanation why.

Answer (score 0):

Replace CAST with to_number() and add guid. Test your select first, then insert...:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    sys_guid() guid 
    To_Number(SUBSTR(zip_code, 1,1)) as  t_val1,
    zip_code as t_val2
 FROM OTHER_TABLE_T
/
```

Distinct GUID example:

```
SELECT sys_guid() gid, deptno
  FROM
 (
 SELECT distinct deptno FROM scott.emp
 )
ORDER BY deptno
/

GID                                 DEPTNO
-------------------------------------------
DC9B9132492C1A45E04011AC3EEB463A    10
DC9B9132492B1A45E04011AC3EEB463A    20
DC9B9132492A1A45E04011AC3EEB463A    30
```

Comment: Thanks for the `to_number` suggestion, but this doesn't really solve my main problem. If I introduce a sys_guid into the select, then the distinct wouldn't filter out any duplicate lines (e.g. if I have several rows with the same zip_code, but a different other column).

Comment: @mhd - Then get rid of distinct - use group by or exists operator etc... Why use guid instead of some type of sequence...

Comment: Design choice here at work, most tables have GUIDs as ID PKs. And yes, there are several workarounds possible, and I've solved my problem with a simple wrapping SELECT. But that's a bit like the old "Doctor, my arm hurts when I do this"/"Then don't do it" joke. For my own personal education, I'd like to know what's wrong with the original, whether my concept of the relational model is just bad or whether it's just a bug.

Comment: @mhd - I cannot really comment on guids as PKs. Probably it would be simpler to identify the row in a table with some numeric value that comes from sequence then with a guid. Just an opinion. And there are ways to avoid distinct or wrap the select as you wrote to make it work with guids.